# How to insert two IDs on two tables on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables `tbl_sales` and `tbl_customer`

[image]

When I click 'Confirm Order' I want my `tbl_sales` to contain this values

```
sale_id  customer_id  product_name  product_qty  product_price
   1         1         Coca-Cola2       25             13
   2         1           Pepsi          25             12
   3         1           Nescafe        25             12
```

And my `tbl_customer` to contain this values

```
customer_id  customer_firstname  customer_address    customer_contact
    1              John           #3 St. Boulevard     123456789123
```

How do I achieve this using PHP and MySQL?

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: How it's look your function adding data to MySQL?

Comment: @eol how to give an ID on the `customer` and at the same time attach the product/s he ordered to him

Comment: No pictures, thanks - and are you sure that you want to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First insert a new record into the table `tbl_customer` and get the last insert id. With that id insert the record to the table `tbl_sales`. Assuming you're using `pdo` and `auto_increment` something like this:

```
//create a prepared statement for inserting into the customer table
$prepStmt= $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_customer (customer_firstname, customer_address, customer_contact)
    VALUES(:firstname, :address, :contact)");

$prepStmt->execute(array(
        "firstname" => $_POST['yourFormValueForFirstname'], //TODO: add validation for $_POST variables because of XSS-attacks!
        "address" => $_POST['yourFormValueForAddress'],
        "contact" => $_POST['yourFormValueForContact']
    ));

//now get the last inserted id
$lastCustomerId = $pdo->lastInsertId();

//create a prepared statement for inserting into sales table
$prepStmt= $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_sales (customer_id,product_name, product_qty, product_price)
        VALUES(:customerId, :prodName, :prodQ,:prodPrice)");

//and use the last inserted customer id for the new sales record
$prepStmt->execute(array(
            "customerId" => lastCustomerId,
            "prodName" => $productName,
            "prodQ" => $productQuantity,
            "prodPrice" => $productPrice
        ));
```

Comment: Do I have to manually insert a record to the `tbl_customer` everytime I want to make another sale? I use `mysqli_` but thanks, I'll try to understand this `pdo`. And yes my `customer_id` and `sales_id` have AI.

Comment: No, you could just check if a customer with e.g. the email address has already purchased something. So you make another select query where you look for the unique column. If no row is returned you insert a new record, else you use the `customer id` of the returned row.

Comment: For mysqli getting the last insert id is pretty similar. Instead of `$pdo->lastInsertId()` use `$mysqli->insert_id`